# why cant I add date that I got from an xlsx file to my plot?

Tags: r

I have imported some values from a xlsx file and I am trying to put every value in a plot. but I keep getting this error:

```
Error in plot.window(...) : need finite 'xlim' values
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In min(x) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
2: In max(x) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
```

I have tried using the strptime function but I am still getting the same error.

[These are the values of my table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/14baW.png)

and this is what I am trying to do

```
plot(strptime(my_data$Datum,"%d/%m/%Y"),my_data$Studiepunten,type="l",xlab="Date",ylab="Units Sold")
```

Comment: You need to provide the data using `dput(my_data)`. Copy and paste the results into your question. A picture of the data is not useful because it does not tell us how the date information is stored (e.g. characters, date/time object, factor, etc).

Comment: @dcarlson this is what I am getting if I do dput: structure(list(Datum = c("31-11-2020", "31-1-2021", "31-3-2021"
), Studiepunten = c(5L, 20L, 30L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))

Comment: You told `strptime` that the parts of each date were separated by "/" but they are separated by "-". Also your example has an invalid date. There is no date November 31 so that produces a missing value `NA`.